# ROC Curve for Kfold in Scikit-learn. Works good for StratifiedKfold but show error for Kfold

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, roc

I want to plot **ROC Curve** using **Kfold cross validation**. However, the code that is given at `scikit-learn` page is for `StratifiedKfold`. Thus, when I change the `StratifiedKfold` by `Kfold`, it is giving me `None` results in plots. What can be the problem?

Sample code is at [ScikitLearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-crossval-py)

I changed the `StratifiedKfold` by `Kfold` but it is not working.

Comment: Show us the code you used.

Comment: @Andronicus Thanks for your feedback. I cannot copy the code in the comments. However, the code is present at the below given link       https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-crossval-py

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle the data before cutting the folds:

`cv = KFold(n_splits=6, shuffle=True)`

Explanation:

`StratifiedKFold` cuts folds such that proportion of classes in each fold is roughly the same as in the whole dataset. `Kfold` does not do that and just cuts folds from samples in the order of their appearance in the dataset. Hence you may or may not get all present classes in all folds. In this case or `Iris` dataset, the samples are sorted by class, this can be see from the target `y`:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Hence in the case of 6 fold split, you only get one class in a fold most of the time, and the whole model training breaks. Shuffling allows KFold to pick up both classes in every fold, and all works fine.

Comment: Thank you for such a nice explanation. In my case I have 40 samples. Thus, I wanted to apply 40 folds. But, with shuffling, still the result is nun. In other way, we can say my problem utilizes LOO cross validation. Do you have any idea, how to handle this?

Comment: 40 folds for 40 samples is way to many. Usually, no more that 10 folds. And the lower the number of samples, the fewer folds you'd want, because more training samples per fold give better model quality.

Comment: Bro you are right. But, actually the previous studies conducted on the dataset utilizes LOO cross validation. To compare my method with previous methods, I am trying to draw ROC for LOO validation scheme. Is there anyway to plot ROC for LOO cross validation???

Comment: I think this deserves a separate question. One needs to compute statistic on the left-out sample(s)? so may be some extra coding is required. In this question I have shown you why KFold didn't work and what could make it work, i.e. answered the question asked

Comment: Thanks bro for your feedback.